# Compiling tensorflow/models/rnn/translate:translate with local numpy

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run the neural machine translation demo on a gpu. The GPU example in tensorflow's getting started page works.

```sh
$ bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/tutorials_example_trainer --use_gpu
```

produces the expected output.

But when I try to compile the [translation demo](http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html):

```sh
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda --verbose_failures //tensorflow/models/rnn/translate:translate
```

it fails:

```sh
...
____Loading package: @jpeg_archive//
____Loading package: @png_archive//
____Loading package: @re2//
____Loading complete.  Analyzing...
____Found 1 target...
____Building...
____[0 / 2] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt
____[25 / 324] Executing genrule @six_archive//:copy_six
____[237 / 1,193] Executing genrule @png_archive//:configure [for host]
____[242 / 1,193] Executing genrule //third_party/gpus/cuda:cuda_check
____[361 / 1,193] Executing genrule //google/protobuf:protobuf_python_internal_copied_filegroup_genrule
____From Executing genrule @png_archive//:configure:
____From Executing genrule @png_archive//:configure [for host]:
____From Executing genrule @jpeg_archive//:configure:
____From Executing genrule @jpeg_archive//:configure [for host]:
____[677 / 1,193] Compiling tensorflow/core/kernels/argmax_op.cc
____From Compiling tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc:
tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc: In function 'tensorflow::Status tensorflow::{anonymous}::TF_StringTensor_GetPtrAndLen(const TF_Tensor*, tensorflow::int64, tensorflow::int64, const char**, tensorflow::uint64*)':
tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc:248:14: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   if (offset >= (limit - data_start) || !p || (*len > (limit - p))) {
              ^
tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc:248:53: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   if (offset >= (limit - data_start) || !p || (*len > (limit - p))) {
                                                     ^
tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc: In function 'tensorflow::Status tensorflow::{anonymous}::TF_Tensor_to_PyObject(TF_Tensor*, PyObject**)':
tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc:311:32: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   if (PyArray_NBYTES(py_array) != TF_TensorByteSize(tensor)) {
                                ^
tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc: In function 'void tensorflow::TF_Run_wrapper(TF_Session*, const FeedVector&, const NameVector&, const NameVector&, tensorflow::Status*, tensorflow::PyObjectVector*)':
tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc:416:21: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); ++i) {
                     ^
tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc:430:41: error: 'PyArray_SHAPE' was not declared in this scope
       dims.push_back(PyArray_SHAPE(array)[i]);
                                         ^
tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc:513:21: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   for (int i = 0; i < output_names.size(); ++i) {
                     ^
ERROR: /home/mifs/fs439/bin/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:710:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/python:tf_session_helper' failed: crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error executing command
...
```

Probably because of

```sh
tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc:430:41: error: 'PyArray_SHAPE' was not declared in this scope
       dims.push_back(PyArray_SHAPE(array)[i]);
```

This is probably because the global numpy installation is old and does not know PyArray_SHAPE. I don't have admin rights to update it globally, but I have installed an updated numpy in $HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ using `pip install --user`. If I add the path to the corresponding rule in tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD like this:

```sh
tf_cuda_library(
    name = "tf_session_helper",
    srcs = ["client/tf_session_helper.cc"],
    hdrs = ["client/tf_session_helper.h"],
    copts = numpy_macosx_include_dir + ["-I<path-to-local-numpy>"] + ["-I/usr/include/python2.7"],
    deps = [
        ":construction_fails_op",
        ":test_kernel_label_op_kernel",
        "//tensorflow/core",
        "//tensorflow/core:direct_session",
        "//tensorflow/core:kernels",
        "//tensorflow/core:lib",
        "//tensorflow/core:protos_cc",
    ],
)
```

it complains:

```sh
ERROR: <tensorflow-dir>/tensorflow/python/BUILD:710:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow/python:tf_session_helper: The include path '/home/mifs/fs439/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include' references a path outside of the execution root..
ERROR: <tensorflow-dir>/tensorflow/python/BUILD:710:1: in cc_library rule //tensorflow/python:tf_session_helper: The include path '/home/mifs/fs439/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include' references a path outside of the execution root..
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/models/rnn/translate:translate' failed; build aborted.
____Elapsed time: 18.559s
```

How can I tell tensorflow to use the local numpy version?

(gcc 4.9.3, bleeding edge tensorflow + bazel, local numpy 1.10.1, ubuntu 12.04)

EDIT:

When I follow the instructions from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/109) as suggested by syncd I get

```sh
ERROR: /home/mifs/fs439/bin/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:710:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//tensorflow/python:tf_session_helper':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc':
  'third_party/numpy/arrayobject.h'
  'third_party/numpy/ndarrayobject.h'
  'third_party/numpy/ndarraytypes.h'
  'third_party/numpy/npy_common.h'
  'third_party/numpy/numpyconfig.h'
  'third_party/numpy/_numpyconfig.h'
  'third_party/numpy/npy_endian.h'
  'third_party/numpy/npy_cpu.h'
  'third_party/numpy/utils.h'
  'third_party/numpy/_neighborhood_iterator_imp.h'
  'third_party/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h'
  'third_party/numpy/old_defines.h'
  'third_party/numpy/__multiarray_api.h'
  'third_party/numpy/npy_interrupt.h'.
Target //tensorflow/models/rnn/translate:translate failed to build
```

Various attempts to add them to hdrs in the tf_cuda_library rule do not help:

```sh
hdrs = ["client/tf_session_helper.h"] + glob([
    "**/arrayobject.h",
    "numpy/*.h",
    "**/numpy/*.h",
]),
```

Comment: How are you specifying the path to the local numpy? I believe an absolute path should work, but could be mistaken.

Comment: I'm using an absolute path. Using a relative path to a symlink to numpy in the workspace results in many "this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by..." errors for the tf_cuda_library rule followed by a list of the numpy *.h files

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is presented [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/109).

Create a link to `$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy` in the `tensorflow/third_party` dir and edit `-Ithird_party` to `tensorflow/python/build` and `tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl`

Comment: I get "this rule is missing dependency declarations" with this solution - see my updated post

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **very** nasty workaround if you get the "undeclared inclusion(s) in rule" errors:

1.) Pick a path in your gccs build-in include directories (i.e. one of the cxx_builtin_include_directory paths in bazel-workspace/tools/cpp/CROSSTOOL - should be equal to those given by g++ -v bla.cc)

2.) Lets say you picked directory *dir* .Create a directory called "bla" within *dir*

3.) In *dir*/bla, create a symlink to your numpy include directory (ln -s .../core/include/numpy .)

4.) Add "*dir*/bla" to  tensorflow/python/BUILD and tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl as described in the link.

5.) Feel guilty but happy that it compiles